# How to protect db when using npm mysql library?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, performance, database-connection

If there are many requests of db server at the same time saying that the QPS is 100, and the DB server has a connection limit saing 1000, so if the requests are slow queries which will eventually got `inactivity timeout`, at this time what shoud i do to prevent the `npm package` [mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) from creating new connection?

Because the `npm package` [mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) will remove the connection object from the connection object pool with fatal error like `inactivity timeout` and leave space for creating new connection.

Comment: 100 queries/second is about the median.  max_connections = 1000 is rather high.  Connections _should_ be dropped after some period of inactivity (wait_timeout).  Clients should not hang onto connections for long periods of time (hours).  Aside from 'npm', what is the problem?

Comment: @Rick James, the built-in connection pool will remove the bad connection object which may have got an fatal error like `inactivity timeout` from the pool and the socket will send a `FIN` packet and then the pool will create new one. If the timeout queries last for hours and the db server will use out of its connections at last.

Answer (score 0):

For high load, you should use connection pools with persistent connections. Those are usually available in hight level query builders and ORMs like [knex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/knex) and [sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize).

But if you don't want use them, you can also try [native pools](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections).

Comment: thanks for answering. But the pools of [mysq](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections) will remove an fatal-error connection and create a new connection if the requests continue which may use out the connection limit of the db server

Comment: You should both configure max connections number, max pools and max connection timeout to avoid reaching connection limit. You can also kill connections which run for a too long time manually. There is no magic which will somehow solve this problem in another way.

Comment: If you got high load, it also could create many connections even if you set the max connections number like 10. For example ,i request the db with QPS 1000 and each of the request is a slow query with many `count `and `order by` without using indexes, if i simulate requesting 40 minutes, the DB server got 450 connections!

Comment: Needing 450 connections tells me that you have some slow queries (that need to be investigated) or the connections fail to `disconnect` in a timely manner.